# C++ How to store two data types in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, hashmap, dimension

I need to store two values width different data types in a vector, example:

```
vector<HWND, long> hwnd;
```

And then get by index and access to the two values:

```
hwnd[0] // Get HWND and long
hwnd[1] // Get HWND and long
```

Is it correct to ask for a vector solution to this or maybe use a hashmap solution? I haven't used hashmap yet that's why I'm wondering this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `std::vector<std::pair<HWND, long>> hwnd`

Comment: A structure or class? That's how you traditionally kept related data together.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes that's the first I thought but there must be a simplier solution. Thanks.

Comment: I would argue that using a simple `struct` *is* the simple solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While using a `std::pair` is a correct solution, it loses some clarity because you would access the elements like this:

```
hwnd[0].first
hwnd[0].second
```

which makes it absolutely not clear which is a handle and which is a long.

You should instead use a struct (I'm using count here as an example of use case, your own long might have an entirely different meaning):

```
struct HandleCount {
    HWND handle;
    long count;
};
```

So your code would look like:

```
std::vector<HandleCount> hwnd;

hwnd[0].handle
hwnd[0].count
```

So, while you lose a little bit of simplicity by using a supplementary type, you instead benefit in simplicity of *understanding* the code.

Comment: And could you show how to assign values to `hwnd` after creating a vector of struct?

Answer (score 3):

You can use class `std::pair` declared in header `<utility>`

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

//...

std::vector<std::pair<HWND, long>> hwnd;
```

To place elements in the vector you can use methods `push_back` or `emplace_back`
For example

```
hwnd.emplace_back( new_hwnd, new_long );
```

or

```
hwnd.push_back( { new_hwnd, new_long } );
```

or

```
hwnd.push_back( std::make_pair( new_hwnd, new_long ) );
```

To access values you can write for example

```
hwnd[0].first; 
hwnd[0].second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `std::pair` or `std::tuple` or a user defined data type.

```
vector<pair<HWND, long>> a;
a.push_back(make_pair(val1, val2));
cout << a[0].first << endl;
cout << a[0].second << endl;
```

It's worth noting that the advantage of pair and tuple is that they define the common operators such as `operator<` and `operator==` so you don't have to redefine them if you are going to want to say, sort that vector or apply other operations to it which would require the operators. If that's not required, probably just define your own struct.

A map is used to store a mapping between a key and a value, so if that is what you actually need, then use that.

```
map<int, string> mp;
mp.insert(make_pair(1, "bob"))
mp.insert(make_pair(2, "tim"))
cout << *map.find(2)  << endl;
// prints "tim"
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 you can do it using [tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
std::vector< std::tuple<HWND, long> > hwnd;
```

Add new elements with any of:

```
hwnd.push_back( {handle, count} );
hwnd.push_back( std::make_tuple(handle, count) );
```

and retrieving the elements is done with:

```
HWND handle0 = std::get<0>(hwnd[0]);
long count0  = std::get<1>(hwnd[0]);
HWND handle1 = std::get<0>(hwnd[1]);
long count1  = std::get<1>(hwnd[1]);
```

Note that using tuples you aren't restricted to two elements.

Comment: Hmm, `std::tuple<>` wasn't meant to replace simple data structures. I'm not so sure this would be the _best practice_ c++11 way.

Comment: actually yes and it depends. I meant that it is the C++11 way with respect to you using `std::pair`. I'm rephrasing with a less strong statement. Thanks!